# Использование слова «чудотворный»

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, словосочетания

Можно ли использовать слово **чудотворный** со словом **Бог**?

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя, поскольку это слово указывает на *результат* сотворения (*что сотворено* чудесным образом, какое чудо), а не на творца (*кто сотворяет* чудо; ср.: рукотворный). В отношении к богу применимо **чудотворящий**:

> Господь *чудотворящий*, который умножил хлеба и пятью хлебами насытил
>   пять тысяч алчущих, умножает непрестанно в тысячах алтарей и Кровь
>   свою пречистую, чтобы насытить и напоить ею миллионы верных.

https://www.eparhia-saratov.ru/Content/Books/158/30.html

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя. Бог - это субъект, а слово "чудотворный" используется только в отношении объектов.

Наверное, можно подобрать подходящий эпитет со значением "творящий чудеса" (мне что-то так вот сразу ничего в голову не приходит), но зачем? Бог по определению ассоциируется с чудесами, в результате получится "масло масляное".